# How to use eclipse as an IDE for hibernate-tools

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have cloned hibernate tools and I can build it from maven, however after running *mvn eclipse:eclipse* I get a .classpath that looks like

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="h2/target/hibernate-tools-tests-h2-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="h2/target/hibernate-tools-tests-h2-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/hibernate-tools-tests-maven-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/local-repo/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/local-repo/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/local-repo/com/h2database/h2/1.4.195/h2-1.4.195.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/local-repo/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="maven/target/local-repo/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
```

These jars are in my ~/.m2/repository but the specified location does
not in fact have the jars

```
./hibernate-tools/test/maven/target/local-repo/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1

dom4j-1.6.1.pom
dom4j-1.6.1.pom.sha1
_remote.repositories
```

How can I use eclipse on this projecgt?